# Is it possible to execute a code in runtime when gets updated over the air (OTA)?

Tags: programming, eeprom, flash

I would like to build a lib like ArduinoOTA but with no downtime at runtime. To achieve that I am wondering if it is possible to create a simple setup and loop code to

1. Check for new releases
2. If we have a new one start download it
3. As download routine is not finished keep running the current release
4. When download has finished, swap current release to the new one.
5. Now the normal routine is running the new release.

I am pretty interested if it is possible to do by myself something like that.

I didn't find any paper or articles similar to this and I don't known if this is a challenge for Arduino scope or C/C++.

Maybe I am saying something bizarre but I have been thinking of save new release into flash memory, point to it and discard the old release from flash memory.

Comment: On an 8-bit Arduino? No. Or certainly not without a huge amount of work.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? ... maybe it can be done without reflashing the program

Comment: @jsotola I am trying to deploy releases over the air without downtime in the middle of this process. That is, I want to download a new release from Internet and keep running the old one until the new has been downloaded.

Comment: that does not actually answer the question, it is a repeat of your question .... is it possible that an "update" could involve changing only some parameters that could be read from an online server

Comment: The "update" I am talking about is a new version of the current sketch previously uploaded to Arduino manually.

Comment: but the new sketch doesn't have everything on the same address. how will the instruction pointer be set to a good address. and what will initialize the new variables. reset is necessary

Comment: and about what MCU is it?

Comment: @Juraj Hmm make sense! Do you have any paper a could read for something like that? These questions is for my final paper and I am trying to do update OTA like we see in Web or Apps. It would be awesome if we have the same in IoT ecosystem.

Comment: The MCU will be an Arduino or ESP8266. I read both use Modified Harvard Architecture and can share instruction and data code. But you have a point when saying the MCU will don't know how to know the complete path for instruction pointer

Comment: Sorry. ESP8266 ESP-01

Comment: esp8266 has ArduinoOTA library supported by the  SDK. for SAMD Arduino has OTA anf I made this kind of OTA for ATmega  https://github.com/jandrassy/ArduinoOTA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On many Arduinos the processor is only a few dollar part.  You are asking for a feature that only starts appearing on platforms where the processor is over an order of magnitude higher in price.  Further, such inexpensive processors normally run a single program.  Running a sketch while managing a download & update would best be done by two programs existing in an operating system.  Again, likely requiring a processor an order of magnitude higher in price.

Instead, consider implementing your design using two different Arduinos.  Swapping one out for the other after updating.   Hot swapping may not be trivial.  This really depends on how your application interfaces with the world. But likely will be much easier than solving the problem of designing the supporting software to make sketch updates transparent to the Arduino user.

Comment: This is honestly the most simple and yet fun to implement. It is not be a perfect solution but definitely could attend me. Thank you so much for that!